# How do I keep a python script running continually?

Tags: php, python, execute

I have read through a bunch of forums and still no luck.. I have a php file that executes a python file (liveSensor.py). It runs the py file once and stops, how to I keep the file open in the background? If I run sudo python liveSensor.py in the command line it just runs once as well but if I put sudo python -i liveSensor.py it stays open. How to I do this in php?

php file -

```
<?php
$try = exec('python sensor.py');
print_r ($try);
?>
```

In the liveSensor.py file I have 2 vibration sensors that are being detected and then passing that info into sqlite, then my php file retrieves that data and using ajax I can display it. All of this works great except launching the py file continually..

py script -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sqlite3

KnockPin = 12 
ShockPin = 13 



inning = 1
runs = 0
strikes = 0
balls = 0

print ("Welcome to Bases Loaded")



def setstr():
    global strikes
    strikes = 0
    global balls
    balls = 0




def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)         
    GPIO.setup(KnockPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.setup(ShockPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)




def knock(ev=None):

with sqlite3.connect('basesLoaded.db') as conn:

    global strikes
    global inning


    strikes += 1

    if strikes ==0:

        pass
    elif strikes == 1:


        conn.execute("UPDATE bl set STRIKE = 1 WHERE ID =1");

        print ("Strike 1 :", conn.total_changes);

    elif strikes == 2:


        conn.execute("UPDATE bl set STRIKE = 2 WHERE ID=1");

        print ("Strike 2 :", conn.total_changes);

    elif strikes == 3:
        global inning
        inning +=1
        conn.execute("UPDATE bl set STRIKE = 0 WHERE ID=1");
        conn.execute("UPDATE bl set INNING = inning WHERE ID=1");

        print ("Strike 3 Your Out :", conn.total_changes);
        setstr()
        print ("Inning Number :", inning);

def shock(ev=None):
    with sqlite3.connect('basesLoaded.db') as conn:

        global balls

        balls += 1

        if balls ==0:
            pass
        elif balls == 1:

            conn.execute("UPDATE bl set BALL = 1 WHERE ID=1");
            conn.commit()
            print ("Ball 1 :", conn.total_changes);


        elif balls == 2:

            conn.execute("UPDATE bl set BALL = 2 WHERE ID=1");
            conn.commit()
            print ("Ball 2 :", conn.total_changes); 

        elif balls == 3:

            conn.execute("UPDATE bl set BALL = 3 WHERE ID=1");
            conn.commit()
            print ("Ball 3 :", conn.total_changes);

        elif balls == 4:

             global runs
            runs += 1
            conn.execute("UPDATE bl set BALL = 0 WHERE ID=1");
            conn.execute("UPDATE bl set RUN = 'runs' WHERE ID=1");
            conn.commit()
            print ("Run Scored! score is :", runs); 
            setstr()




def register_callbacks():
     GPIO.add_event_detect(ShockPin, GPIO.FALLING, callback=shock, bouncetime=2500)
     GPIO.add_event_detect(KnockPin, GPIO.FALLING, callback=knock, bouncetime=2500) 



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        setup()
        register_callbacks()

    except KeyboardInterrupt: 
        destroy()
```

This returns my 'Welcome to Bases Loaded' message in the browser but the py file wont stay open to detect the sensors.

Comment: You should (obviously?) provide more info on what is liveSensor.py actually doing.

Comment: python daemon: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+daemon and why would you launch it with php?

Comment: I launch it with php as the way the game is setup is using my tablet as the scoreboard from the pitchers mound. So using apache2 Ican stream on my local network. Also I am going to eventually have the ability to choose from multiple games that I will program in the future. I am just more  comfortable building the interface in php/html

Comment: @Aif , I updated the question with more info

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of interaction you need to build a server script that runs in a separate process and uses a communication protocol, like a database for instance.  If you think about it, the PHP runtime has no control about the python script: it can run it and provide you with the output, but how is the PHP runtime going to know when and how you may need results from the script?

A better approach would be to make a REST service with Python that provides the sensor data on demand and use Javascript to make AJAX requests and get the data as needed.

Comment: Hey @Cyb3rFly3r I am using sqlite3, apache2, php5 and ajax for this, it all works great as long as I start the py script from the command line or idle first.. Just cant get php to keep the py file open..